# Angular ui-router - Two way binding for objects in resolve in parent/child states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm stuck with a particularly bad inheritance issue. Essentially, ui-router will two-way bind data that is passed to a child state from its parent via `resolve`. Works great. However, if (from the child state) I try to change the reference to the object itself instead of just an attribute, this isn't reflected in the parent.

[This attached plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yLgGhnaE1lGgh6RWaVkH?p=preview) shows the issue - if you update the value in the child , the parent changes. However, if you click "New Object", only the child value will change.

I'm assuming this is a weird dot notation issue, any help? If so, what would the proper syntax in `resolve` be (i.e. something like `state.object` rather than just `object`..?)

Comment: One potential workaround that I've found is by using `angular.extend` - i.e. instead of `$scope.object = newObject` you can use `angular.extend($scope.object, newObject)`

Comment: if you anyways want to change the parent object why dont you use $scope.$parent.object instead?